# Several functions without global variable

Tags: python, list, variables, global

I want to know how I can make this code without global variables.

I have tried myself but it seems like it involves return, but then It won't go back to the "menu" (main_list). The point of this code is to always return to the menu except when pressing "3" (exit program).

Sorry for the big (and bad) code, I appreciate all the help I can get.

```
import sys
word = []
desc = []

def main_list():

    print "\nMenu for list \n"
    print "1: Insert"
    print "2: Lookup"
    print "3: Exit program"

    choice = raw_input()
    print "Choose alternative: ", choice

    if choice.isdigit():
        choice = int(choice)
        if choice == 1:
            insert()
        elif choice == 2:
            look()
        elif choice == 3:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print "Error: Not a valid choice \n", main_list()
    else:
        print "Error: Not a valid choice \n", main_list()

def insert():
    ins = raw_input("Word to insert: ")
    if ins not in word:
        word.append (ins)
    else:
        print "Error: Word already exist \n", main_list()       
    desc.append(raw_input ("Description of word: "))
    main_list()

def look():
    up = raw_input("Word to lookup: ")
    if up not in word:
        print "Error: Word not found \n", main_list()
    i = 0
    while up != word[i]:
        i += 1
    if up == word[i]:
        print "Description of word: ", desc[i]
    main_list()
```

Comment: Move it into a class and initialise the globals as class variables, the functions can become class functions.

Comment: Consider posting this on Code Review instead; just be sure that A) it's not broken code B) you read the on-topic guide to be sure how, *and what* to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Xeno said, you need a `while` loop to continually loop over the input.  For your case, I would suggest a `do-while` loop, but Python does not have a built-in `do-while`, so you will need to emulate one, possibly something like this:

```
while True:
    # do stuff
    if condition:
        break
```

To get rid of the global variables, you will need to pass variables into your methods and return out of them.

```
def insert(word, desc):
    # do stuff
```

Now, I noticed you call `main_list()` at the end of `insert()` and `look()`.  Do not do this.  You do not need a new instance every time, you need to return back to the current instance.  So, set up something like this:

```
def main_list():
    # do stuff

    while True:
        # do more stuff

        if condition:
            break

    # do more stuff

def insert():
    # do stuff - return any new value; otherwise, just let it auto-return

def look():
    # do stuff - return any new value; otherwise, just let it auto-return
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should use a while loop in your main function, so that it will only exit when you want it to:

So something like this:

```
while choice != 3:
    if choice == 1:
        insert()
    elif choice == 2:
        look()
    elif choice == 3:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print "Error: Not a valid choice \n"
    print "1: Insert"
    print "2: Lookup"
    print "3: Exit Program"
    choice = int(raw_input("choose alternative")
```

Edit: As Prune so nicely stated below, I did not give any reasoning for my answer, so here goes:

The reason your code wasn't going back to the loop you wanted to, is that you are using an if-statement to run your loop.  A while loop will allow you to repeat the desired process until you need to break.  And if you want a reason not to use the main_list() function called from your other functions, look at Hosch250's answer

Comment: This is a code review addition; it doesn't address the given question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, clean up that main loop as the previous "answer" suggests: delete the exit clause and just leave the while loop when you're done.

Second, pass word and desc in the parameter list.  Add them to the "def" lines in your functions.

Third, remove the calls to main_list from your print statements; you'll return to the main program when you run off the bottom of the function.

Does this get you moving?

```
word = []
desc = []
menu = \
    "\nMenu for list \n" \
    "1: Insert\n" \
    "2: Lookup\n" \
    "3: Exit program"

choice = raw_input(menu)
while choice != 3:
    if choice.isdigit():
        choice = int(choice)
        if choice == 1:
            insert(word, desc)
        elif choice == 2:
            look(word, desc)
        else:
           print "Error: Not a valid choice \n", main_list()
    else:
        print "Error: Not a valid choice \n", main_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest thing to do with your existing code would be to restructure it something like this, which makes `main_list()` drive the whole process by adding a `while` loop to it, and have it just pass the shared variables to each of the other functions as arguments.

```
def main_list():
    word = []
    desc = []

    print "\nMenu for list"
    print "  1: Insert"
    print "  2: Lookup"
    print "  3: Exit program"

    while True:
        choice = raw_input()
        print "Alternative chosen: ", choice

        if choice.isdigit():
            choice = int(choice)
            if choice == 1:
                insert(word, desc)
            elif choice == 2:
                look(word, desc)
            elif choice == 3:
                break
            else:
                print "Error: Not a valid choice"
        else:
            print "Error: Not a valid choice"

def insert(word, desc):
    ins = raw_input("Word to insert: ")
    if ins not in word:
        word.append(ins)
    else:
        print "Error: Word already exist"
    desc.append(raw_input("Description of word: "))

def look(word, desc):
    up = raw_input("Word to lookup: ")
    if up not in word:
        print "Error: Word not found"
    i = 0
    while up != word[i]:
        i += 1
    if up == word[i]:
        print "Description of word: ", desc[i]

main_list()
```

Answer (score -1):

Encapsulate it in a `class`. This way the word list can be held within the class instance. It's not global and you don't need to pass it around.

```
class main_list(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.words = {}

    def run(self):

        while(True):
            print "\nMenu for list \n"
            print "1: Insert"
            print "2: Lookup"
            print "3: Exit program"

            choice = raw_input()
            print "Chose alternative: ", choice

            if choice.isdigit():
                choice = int(choice)
                if choice == 1:
                    self.insert()
                elif choice == 2:
                    self.look()
                elif choice == 3:
                    break
                else:
                    print "Error: Not a valid choice"
            else:
                print "Error: Not a valid choice"

    def insert(self):
        ins = raw_input("Word to insert: ").lower()
        if ins not in self.words:
            desc = raw_input("Enter description of word: ")
            self.words[ins] = desc
        else:
            print "Error: Word already exist"

    def look(self):
        up = raw_input("Word to lookup: ").lower()
        if up in self.words:
            print "description of `%s` is `%s`" % (up, self.words[up])
        else:
            print "Error: Word %s not found" % up

ml = main_list()
ml.run()
```

Note that I changed to code to use a dictionary. This will avoid needing two separate lists to hold `word` and `description` and give faster look ups.

Comment: It would help if down voters could leave a comment so that I can improve my answer if appropriate.